# Python Assistance regarding the appearance of points

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
import re
import sys
import string
import os
from random import *

def menu():
    print("Welcome To A Password Generator And Checker")
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input("""
1) Generate Password
2) Check Password
3) Quit
"""))

            if choice == 1:
                gp()
            elif choice == 2:
                print("""
- Requirments -

You Must Include:
~ Uppercase Letter
~ Lowercase Letter
~ Number
~ Symbol
""")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("""
Point System:
~1 Uppercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 Lowercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 From 0-9 = 5 Points
~1 Allocated Symbol = 5 Points
~If Has All Add 10 Points
    """)
                passwd = input("Enter Your Desired Password: ")
                passwdVal(passwd)
            elif choice == 3:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Goodbye")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                sys.exit()
        except ValueError:
                    os.system("cls")
                    print("Please select a legitimate option")







def passwdVal(passwd):
    points = 0
    while passwd:  
        if (len(passwd)<8 or len(passwd)>24):
            print("Your Length Is Either Too Big Or Too Small")
            print("Try Again")
            return
        if not re.search("[a-z]",passwd):
            break
        elif not re.search("[0-9]",passwd):
            break
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]",passwd):
            break
        elif not re.search("[!$%^&()_]",passwd):
            break
        else:
            print("Valid Password")
            return



    while points < 35:
        if passwdVal(passwd):
            if 8 <= len(passwd) < 24 :
                print(len(passwd),"Points Added - Length")
                points += (len(passwd))

            else:
                print("Wrong length, it must be 8 to 24 characters")
                continue

            if re.search("[a-z]", passwd):
                print("5 Points Added - Lowercase Letter")
                points += 5

            if re.search("[0-9]", passwd):
                print("5 Points Added - Number")
                points += 5

            if re.search("[A-Z]", passwd):
                print("5 Points Added - Uppercase Letter")
                points += 5

            if re.search("[!$%^&()_]", passwd):
                print("5 Points Added - Symbols")
                points += 5

            if points == 20:
                points += 10

            print("You have {} points".format(points))
            break
        else:
            print("Not a Valid Password")











def gp():
    print("""
Generating Password:""")
    generation = string.ascii_letters+("[!$%^&*()-_=+]")+string.digits
    gp = ("").join(choice(generation) for x in range(randint(8,12)))
    time.sleep(1)





menu()
```

i have given the whole code in case the problem is in the other code. However the problem that im facing is that when i enter a valid password it says valid password, okay. But the points doesn't display when it should. I have tried numerous times but i cannot find the problem. When i enter wrong password it displays the right thing that i want.

Comment: What do you expect `while passwd:` to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `passwdVal(passwd)` has a `return` statement after you print `print("Valid Password")`, which means that the subsequent code (the one summing up the points) does not get executed.

Comment: i deleted it to fix it however now Valid password seems to be repeating itself. Any clue on how to fix it.

Comment: please help i have tried to fix it numerous amount of times, no luck

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a closer look at your password validation function. `menu()` and `gp()` do not have the nicest code style, but at least they seem to work.

## Your `passwdVal()`, commented step-by-step

```
points = 0
while passwd:  # Loop while there is a password...
    if (len(passwd)<8 or len(passwd)>24):
        print("Your Length Is Either Too Big Or Too Small")
        print("Try Again")
        return  # Exit function
    if not re.search("[a-z]",passwd):
        break  # Exit loop
    elif not re.search("[0-9]",passwd):
        break  # Exit loop
    elif not re.search("[A-Z]",passwd):
        break  # Exit loop
    elif not re.search("[!$%^&()_]",passwd):
        break  # Exit loop
    else:
        print("Valid Password")
        return  # Exit function
```

So you are creating a `while`-loop with a condition that evaluates to `True`, as long as your `passwd` is a non-empty string. Since you do not make any changes to this variable, your loop condition will *always* hold true, if you do not force to break the loop or exit the function.

If the password's length does not fit into your bounds, you exit the entire function. if there are characters missing from certain groups, you just exit the loop und go on with the subsequent code of the function, if the password is valid, you exit the function.

This means that your section of calculating points is *only even reached* by the interpreter when there are some characters missing that you would like to see in the password string, because in all other cases you exit the entire function. This seems to be logically incorrect, though it is valid code. You most likely want to remove the `while passwd:` loop, as it is not required here. And on any of your `if`-branches (i.e. on any error found) you just want to print a warning and carry on with the function, even on the generic `else`-branch. Make sure not to exit the function prematurely.

On with your subsequent code:

```
while points < 35:
    if passwdVal(passwd):  # This is a RECURSIVE CALL!
        if 8 <= len(passwd) < 24 :
            print(len(passwd),"Points Added - Length")
            points += (len(passwd))
        else:
            print("Wrong length, it must be 8 to 24 characters")
            continue
        if re.search("[a-z]", passwd):
            print("5 Points Added - Lowercase Letter")
            points += 5
        if re.search("[0-9]", passwd):
            print("5 Points Added - Number")
            points += 5
        if re.search("[A-Z]", passwd):
            print("5 Points Added - Uppercase Letter")
            points += 5
        if re.search("[!$%^&()_]", passwd):
            print("5 Points Added - Symbols")
            points += 5
        if points == 20:
            points += 10

        print("You have {} points".format(points))
        break
    else:
        print("Not a Valid Password")
```

You intend to add points for every character class that you find within the password. What you actually do is (for now ignoring the recursive call above) you add points for all aspects as long as there have been less than `35` points given so far. This means, that you possibly valuate several aspects more than only once. You don't want a loop here either; just walk through your aspects and add points as necessary. At the end, print your point aggregate.

You *must* remove that recursive call there, because it will lead to an infinite stack of function calls.

It seems as if you should think about splitting up your validation function into one function that does the actual validation for a password, and another function that calculates the points for a password.